# using binary files as a dependency

Tags: java, scala, maven, sbt

My program need a set of binary files:

[image]

When I include them directly in a `lib` folder in the project everything works fine. But the issue is I can't include the binary files in the repo. Instead I want to include them as a maven dependency. I packaged them into a single jar and uploaded to a maven repo. 
After I add the dependency to my sbt, indeed I see that they get loaded in the intellij: 
[image]

But the issue is that during run-time I get errors:

```
[error] (run-main-1) java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jscip-0.1.linux.x86_64.gnu.opt.spx in java.library.path
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jscip-0.1.linux.x86_64.gnu.opt.spx in java.library.path
```

Any idea where I am going wrong? Any suggestions on how to debug it?

Answer (score 1):

You have to include your binary dependencies in `java.library.path` and set is as the system parameter for your application `-Djava.library.path=`.

Comment: But when I include the binary files in a jar file and include it as a dependency, doesn't it automatically load the content to the java path?